# Cannot run a c program which includes makemat.c

Tags: 14.04

In my Ubuntu 14.04, When I am trying to compile a c program having the line *#include "makemat.c"* the terminal is showing the following:

```
fatal error: /usr/include/makemat.c: Permission denied
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Well, for a start, you should not include a .c file. Apart from this, the error message is pretty clear. The account you are using is not allowed to read this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do not have [`Read`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) permission on file `/usr/include/makemat.c`

Check your permission using

```
ls -l /usr/include/makemat.c
```

If so, change it's permission using

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr/include/makemat.c
```

Now you can include this file in your program.